# Spring Integration DSL equivalent of <int:gateway ... />

Tags: java, spring, spring-integration, spring-integration-dsl

What would be the Spring Integration DSL way of creating the equivalent of

```
<int:gateway service-interface="MyService" default-request-channel="myService.inputChannel"/>

// where my existing interface looks like
interface MyService { process(Foo foo); }
```

I've not been able to find a factory in `org.springframework.integration.dsl` and none of argument lists for `IntegrationFlows.from(...)` are helping self discovery.

It sort of feels like I'm missing something like a `Java` protocol adaptor from https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration-java-dsl/wiki/Spring-Integration-Java-DSL-Reference#using-protocol-adapters.

```
// I imagine this is what I can't find
IntegrationFlows.from(Java.gateway(MyService.class)
    .channel("myService.inputChannel")
    .get();
```

The only thing I've come across is on an old blog post, but it seems to require annotating the interface with `@MessagingGateway` and `@Gateway`, which I'd like to avoid. See https://spring.io/blog/2014/11/25/spring-integration-java-dsl-line-by-line-tutorial

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We have done that recently in Spring Integration 5.0. With that you really can do this:

```
@Bean
public IntegrationFlow controlBusFlow() {
    return IntegrationFlows.from(ControlBusGateway.class)
            .controlBus()
            .get();
}

public interface ControlBusGateway {

    void send(String command);
}
```

See more info in the latest [blog post](https://spring.io/blog/2017/07/25/spring-integration-5-0-milestone-6-available).

Right now you don't have choice unless declare `@MessagingGateway` on the interface and start the flow from the request channel for that gateway definition.

Comment: Thanks. I'm trying to, bit-by-bit, transform an old XML based app to Spring Boot and Java/DSL config.

Comment: That's good! And as you see there are still some gaps top fix from our side, too.